# Average value of a triangle unipolar function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I am trying to calculate the average value, i expect to be the end result $ \frac{A}2 $( i think so), but i am afraid i mess up with the calculations when i solve it analytically. I would like some help to get the correct  result please. I am interested in for the 'slow' version(analytical solution), no shortcut method.

$$
slope\, between\, [0,\frac{T_o}2] = \frac{2A}{T_0}
$$

$$
slope\, between\, [\frac{T_o}2,T_0] = -\frac{2A}{T_0}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
Avg &= \frac{total\,Area}{total\,time}\\
Avg  &= \frac1{T_0} \int_0^{T_0}x(t)\,dt \\
     &=\frac1{T_0} \Big(\int_0^\frac{T_0}{2}x_1(t)\,dt + \int_\frac{T_0}
       {2}^{T_0}x_2(t)\,dt\Big) \\
     &= \frac1{T_0} \Big(\int_0^\frac{T_0}{2}\frac{2A}{T_0}(t)\,dt - 
        \int_\frac{T_0}{2}^{T_0}\frac{2A}{T_0}(t)\,dt\Big) \\
     &=\frac{2A}{T_0}\frac1{T_0} \Big(\int_0^\frac{T_0}{2}(t)\,dt 
        \int_\frac{T_0}{2}^{T_0}(t)\,dt\Big)\\
     &= \frac{2A}{T_0^2}\Big(\frac{t^2}{2}\Big\vert_0^{\frac{T_0}2} - \frac{t^2}
        {2}\Big\vert_{\frac{T_0}2}^{T_0}\Big)\\
     &= \frac{2A}{2\cdot T_0^2}\Big(t^2\Big\vert_0^{\frac{T_0}2}-
         t^2\Big\vert_{\frac{T_0}2}^{T_0}\Big)\\
     &= \frac{A}{T_0^2}\Big(\frac{T_0^2}{4} - (T_0^2 - \frac{T_0^2}{4})\Big)\\
     &=  \frac{A}{T_0^2}\Big(\frac{T_0^2}{4} - \frac{3T_0^2}{4}\Big)\\
     &=  \frac{A}{T_0^2}\Big( - \frac{2T_0^2}{4}\Big)\\
     &= -\frac{A}2, it \,should\,be\,without\, minus\,symbol,\,right?
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $x_2(t)$ shouldn't just be $\dfrac{-2A}{T_0}t$, since the graph of that function is a line with slope $\dfrac{-2A}{T_0}$ *passing through the origin*, which isn't the line you're interested in. But given that you know the slope and one point on the line, $(T_0,0)$, you can find the actual equation of the line.

Comment: On a different topic, I'm not sure the average value should be $\frac{A}{2}$; that would be true if the area in question were a rectangle with height $A$ and width $T_0$, but that's not the case.

Comment: Should i make $x_2(t) = x_2(t-T_0)$ ? in that case i get Avg = 0(i think)

Comment: You might be overthinking it; since you know the slope of the line and you know that it passes through $(T_0,0)$, so you can find $x_2(t)$ from the point-slope form of a line:$$\begin{align}y-0&=-\dfrac{2A}{T_0}(t-T_0)\\y&=-\dfrac{2A}{T_0}(t-T_0)\\x_2(t)&=-\dfrac{2A}{T_0}(t-T_0)\end{align}$$Then your integral would become$$\frac1{T_0}\left[\int_0^\frac{T_0}{2}\frac{2A}{T_0}t\,dt-\int_\frac{T_0}{2}^{T_0}\frac{2A}{T_0}(t-T_0)\,dt\right],$$and I trust you can evaluate that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize what transpired in the comments (and elaborate a little) so this question won't sit in the "unanswered" queue forever:

Your mistake came when you plugged in $-\frac{2A}{T_0}t$ for $x_2(t)$ when you were solving the integral. Instead, we can see from the equation for the point-slope form of a line that $x_2(t)$ should be $-\frac{2A}{T_0}(t-T_0)$, and that leads to the following integral:

$$\frac1{T_0}\left[\int_0^{\frac{T_0}2}\frac{2A}{T_0}t\,dt-\int_{\frac{T_0}2}^{T_0}\frac{2A}{T_0}(t-T_0)\,dt\right]$$

You can factor out a $\frac{2A}{T_0}$, causing the integral to become the slightly simpler

$$\frac{2A}{T_0^2}\left[\int_0^{\frac{T_0}2}t\,dt-\int_{\frac{T_0}2}^{T_0}(t-T_0)\,dt\right]$$

That evaluates to $\frac A2$, so I was wrong in my second comment. Your original guess was correct! (Good thing I typed this out and actually evaluated my own integral!)